# Running wire through exposed beam

Tags: electrical, wiring

My screened in porch has an exposed beam ceiling, and I'm trying to figure out a wiring issue. The ceiling is actually the roof itself, and there is no space to run wiring through it. I am planning to install a ceiling fan, and was planning to use metal raceway/wiremold. The problem is that at on point I need to get the wiring through one of the beams.

I suppose I could run "down and around" with the raceway, but honestly would look much better if I could go straight through. Can I just notch the beam at the top and run the raceway through? I'd have to do it with the beam in place, so probably would take some creativity with a oscillating multi tool, but think it could work.

Any other ideas?

Edit for additional info: The beams/rafters are sistered 2x12s.

Comment: What type of beams/joists are we dealing with here? Built-up wooden beams or dimensional lumber joists? Engineered wood such as engineered wood I-joists or LVL beams? Some sort of metal member such as a steel I-beam or cold-formed C-joist?

Comment: Are you using individual wires - which require *conduit*, or are you using cable with wiremold as physical protection? That matters because a hole (much easier than a notch) in a beam works as physical protection but may not be legal if you are using individual wires (which require actual rated conduit).

Comment: The engineered drawings for the builder would normally show a detail or if an engineered product reference to manufacturers specs. Typically a dimensional lumber detail would look something like this: https://www.johnbridge.com/vbulletin/attachment.php?attachmentid=3648&stc=1&d=1082560438

Comment: Added info on beams. The raceway I'm referring to (LeGrand Wiremold 500/700) is rated for individual conductors, which was what I'm planning to use. Agree that boring a hole for armored cable or EMT might be easier, but trying to avoid that for aesthetic reasons. I guess the question I'm ultimately asking is whether there's a problem running a surface-mounted raceway through a beam, assuming the notch confirms to allowable depth/placement.

Comment: All new info should be in your question, not down here.

Answer (score 1):

Wiremold V500/700 is covered in the NEC in section 386, where it says:

> 386.10(4) Extension through walls and floors. Surface metal raceway shall be permitted to pass transversely through dry walls, dry
> partitions, and dry floors if the length passing through is unbroken.
> Access to the conductors shall be maintained on both sides of the
> wall, partition, or floor.

It doesn't say beams, but I think it can be interpreted to include beams.

Comment: In this context I think it's safe to say a roof beam or rafter is just a floor joist over your head. Just drill a hole the largest dimension of raceway, suare the edges so it lies flat to the surface and caulk the remaining gap and repaint.

Answer (score 0):

I would place the hole at the center of the height of the beam (ie. near the neutral axis) to maintain beam load bearing capability